# No text output during Arch boot

Tags: boot, arch-linux

I have compiled custom kernel for my Arch. It's not the first time i'm doing it, but this is the first time that i can't see any text output during boot. While compiling the kernel i have unchecked many "framebuffer" items and i think it's related to that. All i see during the boot is just "blob" of white dots on top of the screen, and that "blob" seems to change (like system is trying to output something but can't).
I'm sure it's something trivial (like "turning off this / that module would cause that") but i can't really tell on my own.
What is the problem, and what module is used for outputing boot text before my Nvidia driver loads up?

Comment: Does it boot successfully or is it stuck? Are the "blobs" text, or could this be a [plymouth](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Plymouth) theme? Could you post a screenshot? What are your `grub` options? Are you setting `quiet` at the kernel's entry in `grub.cfg`?

Comment: It's ok, it doesen't stuck. I don't have a plymouth and i can't tell if it's text or not, it's like "attempt" to form some text (judging by the fact that all dots are white). Regarding grub options - it's the same with or without "quiet" kernel parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's a framebuffer resolution problem, try this in the `/etc/default/grub` file to let GRUB detect the good framebuffer resolution

```
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=auto
```

Or try to force GRUB to use normal mode

```
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text
```

Or try to force GRUB to not use framebuffer

```
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT=console
```

Don't forget to generate the config file after changing GRUB options

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: The "console" thing did the trick! Now, it's just a problem that resolution is too low but i guess that this information can tell you what module i have to bring back into kernel right? :)

Comment: I will accept your post as it lead me to the cause: i had to re-enable "Vesa" kernel module :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [`nomodeset`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_Mode_Setting#Disabling_modesetting) kernel parameter?

I haven't compiled a custom kernel, but I've encountered similar-sounding symptoms on boot several times, and adding `nomodeset` has usually helped.

Comment: Tried, no help :)